# Unnest enum_range on Postgres with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to unnest an enum type on Postgres with jOOQ, so that I can use it for a cross-join in a with clause.

What I try to write is an expression like

```
WITH weekdays as (
  SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::week_days)) AS day
)
...
SELECT ...
FROM users
CROSS JOIN weekdays
...
```

The `WITH` statement and `CROSS JOIN` are just for context.

What I'm really struggling with is the `SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL:week_days)) AS day` expression (`week_days` being an enum with values `mon`, `tue`, etc). I just can't figure out how to specify it in jOOQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT unnest(...)` is just a weird, PostgreSQL specific alternative syntax for `SELECT * FROM unnest(...)`. The former isn't supported by jOOQ, the latter is. See this feature request for details:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13187

Now, `enum_range(NULL::weekdays)` is a PostgreSQL specific function, and the fact that it works is a bit weird, but why not. You can point the code generator the the `pg_catalog` schema to generate the `enum_range()` function, or you just use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) for the unavailable parts, e.g.

```java
select(DSL.field(
    "unnest(enum_range(NULL::week_days))", 
    SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asEnumDataType(WeekDays.class)
))
```

Assuming you've used the code generator to get a `WeekDays` class for your enum.